# Компиляция Qt 4.8.7 приложения под Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, build

С Linux'ом практически никогда не работал, поэтому в этой теме абсолютный ноль, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Имеется несколько cpp-шных файлов с программой на Qt. Эти файлы с исходным кодом нужно скомпилировать под Linux, программа писалась на Qt 4.8.7. Пробовал скачать Qt Creator на Linux, но у него можно выбрать только библиотеки Qt >5.0 версии, а мне нужна 4.8.7.

Или это нужно вручную скачивать библиотеки с исходным кодом Qt 4.8.7 и собирать у себя? А после того как собрал, что с ними делать, куда подключать?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, примерный порядок действий, чтобы собрать программу. Заранее, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Можно найти предыдущие версии, возможно придётся предыдущие версии дистрибутива ставить (в виртуальной среде или в chroot). А можно скомпилировать у себя локально, да.

Comment: Для начала: какой linux, что за система сборки, что используется из qt? У qt не полная обратная совместимость, но большинство кода будет работать с библиотеками 5-ой версии. Если же нет, то нужно знать какой у вас линукс. Вангую, что это убунта (16), раз так, лезете на хранилище ppa убунты и смотрите qt примерно той же версии, что вам нужно. Дальше зависит от того, какую систему сборки вы используете. Вангую, что это qmake, раз так, то вам нужно добавить библиотеки qt в PATH (если они были установлены по пути /opt или типа того) и запустить qmake. Все просто

Comment: Попробуйте поставить 4-ю Qt из репозиттория вашего дистрибутива: `sudo yum install qt4-dev` (или qt4-develeop). после этого QtCreator должен увидеть нужную qt.

Comment: Как альтернатива компиляции на qt4 - в сущности, съадаптировать проект и коды из старой версии qt на пятерку не составляет какой-то космической сложности. Как правило, достаточно применить здравый смысл, логику и немного RTFM'а. Если только в проекте не использовались какие-нибудь особенности четвертки или специфичные для какого-то устройства фичи